# Make URL in custom field hyper link

Tags: custom-field

In my WordPress site I have created a custom field for author website link. but I don't know how to make it hyperlink, so people can click on it to surf that website. at this moment it only shows raw text. like: `"www.example.com"`

my code is:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this.

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom-field-name', true);
```

Where custom-field-name is the name of the custom field. You will have to add your custom field name in place of custom-field-name.

Also to open link in new browser window/tab add `target="_blank"`. Always use `esc_url()` for URLs and `esc_html()` when you want to display a value without working HTML.

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Author Website', true );

if ( $value ) {
    // Returns an empty string for invalid URLs
    $url = esc_url( 'http://' . $value );

    if ( '' !== $url ) {
        $display = esc_html( $value );

        print "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$display</a>";
    }
}
```

You should also store the protocol in the field, because some websites might not be available per `http`, just per `https`.

Comment: I already wrapped it with anchor link... but I want to echo out the custom filed value in between the anchor link.. like- 

`<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>">custom field value here</a>`

Comment: OK, what is 'Author Website' is your code. Is this the text that you want to display for link?

Comment: 'Author Website' is the key & 'www.example.com' is the value.

& I want to echo out www.example.com also make it hyperlink, so users can click it to visit the www.examle.com website.

Comment: Should have been working but I think the only problem is that you did not add http:// in your link www.example.com. One more thing, to avoid any issues use a key without spaces and uppercase letters. Use '-' sign instead. For example. 'author-website'

Comment: yes it is working fine. but I was thinking if I could show the url link insted of the text, that would be great. at the moment, my code is `<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>">Visit Website</a>`

& in the front end, it shows "Visit Website", which is not bad at all. but if I could show the actual link itself, that would be better. like "www.example.com"

Comment: Try this once `<a href="http://<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?></a>`

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Please check latest edit in my answer. This will get you displayed www.example.com instead of Visit Website

Comment: yes, that was the solution. the extra "http://" does the trick. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Always use [`esc_attr`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) to escape HTML field value attributes

```
$cf = esc_attr(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field', true ));
echo '<a href="http://' . str_replace("http://", "", $cf) . '">' . $cf . '</a>';
```